# value got overwritten assigning json value within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I produce something like this?

```
{
    "drink": {
        "2": {
            "name": "coke",
            "type": "drink"
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "coke",
            "type": "drink"
        }
    },
    "food": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "1 Hour Snooker",
        "type": "food"
    }
}
```

I have problem producing multiple object under 'drink' object. It got overwritten with my below code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jLgh4at5/

```
var json = {
    "results": {
        "slots": [{
            "id": "3",
                "name": "pepsi",
                "type": "drink"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
                "name": "1 Hour Snooker",
                "type": "food"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
                "name": "coke",
                "type": "drink"
        }]
    }
}

var data = {
    "slots": {

    }
}

json.results.slots.forEach(function (b) {
    if (b["type"] == "food") {
        data.slots["food"] = b;
    } else {
        data.slots["drink"] = b;
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: please include the relevant code *in the question itself*.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array index to resolve the issue.

```
json.results.slots.forEach(function (b,i) {
    if (b["type"] == "food") {
        if(data.slots["food"]) 
            data.slots["food"][i] = {"name":b.name,"type":"food"}; 
        else 
            data.slots["food"] = {};
    } else {
        if(data.slots["drink"]) 
            data.slots["drink"][i] = {"name":b.name,"type":"drink"};
        else 
            data.slots["drink"] = {};
    }
});
```

Or you can optimize the code as shown below.

```
var data = {
    "slots": {
       "food": {},
       "drink": {}
    }
};

json.results.slots.forEach(function (b,i) {
     if (b["type"] == "food") {
        data.slots["food"][i] = {"name":b.name,"type":"food"};
    } else {
        data.slots["drink"][i] = {"name":b.name,"type":"drink"};;
    }
});
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLgh4at5/3/)

Comment: this solve my problem partially, note that I have nested object for the drink object.

Comment: Updated the answer and jsfiddle.